# the clock not displaying the numbers 1 to 12 around the clock

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add numbers around the clock from 1 to 12. The clock is not drawing the numbers. I have the clock drawn and the hour, minute, and second hands drawn.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class ClockPane extends Pane {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    /** Construct a default clock with the current time */
    public ClockPane() {
        setCurrentTime();
    }

    /** Construct a clock with specified hour, minute, and second */
    public ClockPane(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }

    /** Return hour */
    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    /** Set a new hour */
    public void setHour(int hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
        paintClock();
    }

    /** Return minute */
    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    /** Set a new minute */
    public void setMinute(int minute) {
        this.minute = minute;
        paintClock();
    }

    /** Return second */
    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    /** Set a new second */
    public void setSecond(int second) {
        this.second = second;
        paintClock();
    }

    /* Set the current time for the clock */
    public void setCurrentTime() {
        // Construct a calendar for the current date and time
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        // Set current hour, minute and second
        this.hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        this.second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        paintClock(); // Repaint the clock
    }

    private void paintClock() {
        // Initialize clock parameters
        double clockRadius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.8 * 0.5;
        double centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        double centerY = getHeight() / 2;
    
        // Draw circle
        Circle circle = new Circle(centerX, centerY, clockRadius);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    
        // Draw hour markers
        double numberRadius = clockRadius * 0.85;  
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            double numberX = centerX + numberRadius * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 12);
            double numberY = centerY - numberRadius * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 12);
            Text number = new Text(numberX - 5, numberY + 5, "" + i);
            number.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            getChildren().addAll(number);
        }
    
        // Draw second hand
        double sLength = clockRadius * 0.8;
        double secondX = centerX + sLength * Math.sin(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        double secondY = centerY - sLength * Math.cos(second * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        Line sLine = new Line(centerX, centerY, secondX, secondY);
        sLine.setStroke(Color.RED);
    
        // Draw minute hand
        double mLength = clockRadius * 0.65;
        double xMinute = centerX + mLength * Math.sin(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        double minuteY = centerY - mLength * Math.cos(minute * (2 * Math.PI / 60));
        Line mLine = new Line(centerX, centerY, xMinute, minuteY);
        mLine.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    
        // Draw hour hand
        double hLength = clockRadius * 0.5;
        double hourX =
                centerX + hLength * Math.sin((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12));
        double hourY =
                centerY - hLength * Math.cos((hour % 12 + minute / 60.0) * (2 * Math.PI / 12));
        Line hLine = new Line(centerX, centerY, hourX, hourY);
        hLine.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
    
        getChildren().clear(); // Clear the pane
        getChildren().addAll(circle, sLine, mLine, hLine);
    }
    
    

    @Override
    public void setWidth(double width) {
        super.setWidth(width);
        paintClock();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(double height) {
        super.setHeight(height);
        paintClock();
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class DisplayClock extends Application {

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create a clock and a label
        ClockPane clock = new ClockPane();
        String timeString = clock.getHour() + ":" + clock.getMinute() + ":" + clock.getSecond();
        Label lblCurrentTime = new Label(timeString);

        // Place clock and label in border pane
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(clock);
        pane.setBottom(lblCurrentTime);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(lblCurrentTime, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("DisplayClock"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
     * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run the program the numbers are not showing on the clock. I check the imports. It's correct. The code is also correct. I don't know why it's not showing. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: `getChildren().clear(); // Clear the pane` - this clears all the hard work done to get the numbers to display - followed by the adding of the clock and hands which are displayed.  Move the clear to just prior to the "Draw hour markers".  Couldn't help myself and I verified your math on the hour markers - looks good!

Comment: You don't have to clear, recreate and add all new nodes to the clock every time you want to update it.  You can just add everything once and update the properties of the things that need to change when they need to change. [sample clock code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3388637) (the sample is a bit outdated and would need to be updated slightly to work in a modern JavaFX version).